# A "unofficial sucessor" to Lenovo ThinkPad S531

Tags: laptop

I'm helping someone finding a new laptop. The ThinkPad S531 is the only laptop she ever liked and I'm trying to find something similar but in "2019 version". It seems the S531 doesn't have an official successor?

So, first off, the requirements are:

- Brand should be Lenovo, but not strictly ThinkPad
- 15.6" display (preferably brightness of 275 cd/m² or more)
- Display must be non-glossy (matte)
- Intel i7 (1.8+ GHz of newer generations, or 2.2+ of older)
- Fan noise generally low, but of course brief "peaks" are accepted
- 16+ GB of RAM
- Numpad

The computer will be used for office/productivity.

After digging through a lot of different models, I've come across the ThinkPad T590 which seems to deliver on all requirements, except the display gets a hammered in certain reviews (mainly due to brightness).

ThinkPad P53s was also a candidate, although it doesn't have numpad.

We will go with T590 one if there aren't better alternatives.